# Django app not opening from different machine

Tags: python, django

I have a Django server running on 127.0.0.1:8000

When I try to access it from the same machine then I am able to open my application. But when I try to access this app from a different machine by using machinename:8000 then it says 'This site can't be reached'

In my settings.py, I have

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())

and

> ALLOWED_HOSTS=

Is this related to above configuration?

Comment: running your server on `127.0.0.1:8000` makes it only available on the local host. You can run the server on `0.0.0.0:8000` for example, to make it available for another machine of the network

Comment: If your django server is listening on `127.0.0.1` (the loopback interface) then you can't access it from outside the same machine. If you want the app to be reachable from other machines in the same network, make your app listen on `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces) & use the IP of the host machine to connect

Comment: Changing it to 0.0.0.0:8000 says - DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'garuda10.hyd.amzn.co:8000'. You may need to add u'garuda10.hyd.amzn.co:8000' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect with the other computers in the same local network as you you have to run your sever using :

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And in your settings.py put :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

And you have to know your local IP adress of your pc and connect adding ":8000" at the end. To know your computer IP adress:
Bash :
$ ifconfig
Windows :
ipconfig

Comment: I did this,  but when I start server by using "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" it says Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Comment: Did you try with this ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'] ? If it's not working you check the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

Comment: Are you sure that :
--> devices are in the same network 
/ The IP you try is your server/pc IP
/ You add ":8000" at the end of the address