# You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error when I am trying to start my Django server

```
python  manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 18, 2019 - 20:47:09
Django version 1.11, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[18/Aug/2019 20:47:09] "GET /view/stockprice/ HTTP/1.1" 400 16918
[18/Aug/2019 20:47:09] "GET /view/stockprice/ HTTP/1.1" 400 16918
[18/Aug/2019 20:47:09] "GET /view/stockprice/ HTTP/1.1" 400 16918
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add u'127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I have already given 127.0.0.1 in the list of ALLOWED_HOST.

```
SECRET_KEY=BeatTheStreet

DEBUG=True

ALLOWED_HOSTS=['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0']

EVENT_STARTED=True
EVENT_ENDED=

# Production database details
DB_NAME=
DB_USER=
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
```

Pointers to fix this will really help.

I am running server with 0.0.0.0:8000 because of issue I had in [Django app not opening from different machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544896/django-app-not-opening-from-different-machine)

Comment: try `python  manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: @ruhaib I want to run with 0.0.0.0:8000 because of the issue mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544896/django-app-not-opening-from-different-machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django change default runserver port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639085/django-change-default-runserver-port)

Comment: @KARTIKGAUTAM this is not duplicate of what u pointed

Comment: what does the letter "U" mean before the address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens just because `localhost` of your host machine is not localhost of your host server. You can either do

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['<your host ip address>',]
```

or

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*',]
```

although wildcard is not recommended, but useful in dev mode.

[image]
in the given ifconfig, the inet addr `192.168.1.104` is the ip of your host machine, if run `ifconfig` in the host

Comment: try with your host server ip.

Comment: are your devices connected on the same network? also try `DEBUG=True`

Answer (score 1):

If after adding '*' it still doesn't work, you have to find 'request.py' file in **venv** and add your host by yourself: allowed_hosts = "your host"

Answer (score 1):

My solution, my env file template with comments, in settings.py should be as shown in  commented examples

```
# ENV  file template, 
# Install:   pip install python-decouple

# Your Django app secret key without '' or " ", in Django  settings.py  should be as follow:
# SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

SECRET_KEY=secret-key

# Debug state, in Django  settings.py  should be as follow:
# DEBUG = config('DEBUG')

DEBUG=1

# Allowed Hosts in Django  settings.py  should be as follow:
# ALLOWED_HOSTS = [config('ALLOWED_HOST_1'),config('ALLOWED_HOST_2'),config('ALLOWED_HOST_3')]

ALLOWED_HOST_1=127.0.0.1
ALLOWED_HOST_2=192.168.99.100
ALLOWED_HOST_3=localhost

## Settings for Docker SQL postgress, dont use " "

SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=api_db
SQL_USER=api-api-user
SQL_PASSWORD=api-pass
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432


## In Django settings.py should be as follow: 

# DATABASES = {
#     "default": {
#         "ENGINE": config('SQL_ENGINE'),
#         "NAME": config('SQL_DATABASE'),
#         "USER": config('SQL_USER'),
#         "PASSWORD": config('SQL_PASSWORD'),
#         "HOST": config('SQL_HOST'),
#         "PORT": config('SQL_PORT'),
#     }
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have another proyect running, this was my issue xd